# How to parse Google Maps direction api's "overview_polyline"

Tags: google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android get and parse Google Directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964982/android-get-and-parse-google-directions)

There are lat & lng between points tag ,how to parse?
[image]

Comment: In Javascript I use this [function to decode Polyline](http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/googlemaps/encodepolyline/decode.js)s in my Node.JS program.

Comment: if you got this encoded string on server side. [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/312248/Google-Maps-Direction-API-V3-Polyline-Decoder) is decoder in C#

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the Java code in the answer at [android get and parse Google Directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964982/android-get-and-parse-google-directions) (which was in turn taken from [here](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java/)) will do the trick.

Comment: A bit puzzled as to why this example is in Java and not Javascript

Comment: It's in Java because the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) is not a JavaScript API. If one is using it as part of (for example) an Android app, one will tend to write the code interacting with it in Java.