# drawing line between two coordinates on google map

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mkmapview

I am having two coordinate points on Google map. I calculated the distance between that points. But I want to draw a straight line between them. Please help me to draw.

Comment: There are lot of help in this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598322/iphone-how-to-draw-line-between-two-points-on-mapkit

Comment: I already saw this link.But my two points may change each time.So how to change it in route.csv?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/185112).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have to use google  direction api for that follow the [Direction API Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) .
- Make request using **NSURLConnection** with direction api url and pass required addresses from it it and catch its response.
- From that you will get json or xml formatted response, which contains paths in the form of **polyline** encoded string .
- Then parse it and retrieve polyline encoded string.
- You have to simply decode it it then you will get all points of your path and pass it to **viewForOverlay** method of **MKMapViewDelegate** which will draw the path.
- For more information follow my question [Stackoveflow question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835919/drawing-route-partially-not-getting-required-output-in-iphone-mapview) .

If you have any more quires let me know. Hope this will help you....:)