# About tracing routes on Google Maps SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

Is it possible to draw routes between the user's current location and the destination chosen, using Google Maps SDK for iOS ? I've read in many webpages that google does not allow this, is that true ? If so, how it comes that this is possible with the Google Maps app for iPhone ?

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maps SDK allows you to draw Polylines on your map. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/shapes

The Google Directions API gives you Polylines when you query directions from location A to B. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON

I don't think the Maps SDK can directly use the format given by the Direction API though, you will have to handle this yourself. See this thread for a solution to this : [How to decode the Google Directions API polylines field into lat long points in objective-C for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217274/how-to-decode-the-google-directions-api-polylines-field-into-lat-long-points-in)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using **following code** you can get the `GMSPolyline` object which you can add to Google map by setting its map property.

```
+(GMSPolyline *)googlePolylineWithGoogleEncoded:(NSString *)encodedString
{

    GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath pathFromEncodedPath:encodedString];
    GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];


    return polyline;
}
```